# I'm writing a script and it is printing all the spaces in new lines. It is a Bash script

Tags: bash, sed

```
for f in $( tasks/1_uniq/ -type f -follow -print | sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]+/ /g' ); do
        md5sum $f
done
```

And this is what is printing where it finds a space.

```
tasks/1_uniq/two/6/66/test/me
&
my
friends
```

I cant manage to escape the spaces properly.

Answer (score 1):

this is due to word splitting, without quotes after expansions it is split by characters in  '$IFS' (space tab and newline), by double quoting the whole expansion will be taken as an argument. It seems you want to split by newlines. It can be done easily with read;

```
while read filepath; do
    md5sum "$filepath"  # note the double quotes to avoid word splitting
done < <( tasks/1_uniq/ -type f -follow -print | sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]+/ /g' )
```

I don't understand sed command which modifies filenames, it will give wrong filenames, another option

```
find ... -exec md5sum {} +
```

where `...` is replaced with options

Answer (score 1):

From your original code, it seems that your goal is to print out the md5 checksums for all files under a directory. In that case, you can simply use `rhash`

```
rhash -r -M dir/
```

`-r` for recursive and `-M` for md5 hash sum

Comment: when answer  was helpful upvote it or if this answer is what you wanted accept it